# Stepwise regression in R with both direction

Tags: r, regression, stepwise-regression

How does the stepwise regression method work for `both` direction in R with the `step()` function.

I would think that one variable will be placed into the model and then another that will improve the measuring criteria and the significance of the older variable gets assessed. If the older variable's coefficient is not significant the variable will be removed and a next variable will be placed into the model and so forth.

I am not a 100% sure if this is how the step function with `both` do it, but can someone please inform me if this is correct, if not how does the `both` direction criteria implement the stepwise regression in R with `step()`.

Comment: The help `?step` explains it uses AIC (by default), not significance.

Comment: The code can be examined by simply typing `step`. As it says in the help, it uses `add1` and `drop1` each time through ... but unlike that mention in the help it actually does them by calling `drop1` (the backward part) and then `add1` (the forward part).

Comment: A better question might be "Why does R do stepwise regression without penalization?" (as does every other statistical package).  As documented at length on this site, stepwise regression is a mindfield of disasters.  What motivated you to want to use statistical significance or AIC to choose your model for you?

Answer (score 7):

The underlying procedure is beautifully documented in [Chambers & Hastie (eds, 1992; Ch. 6)](http://amzn.com/041283040X) (contrary to what the help page says) on page 237.

`stats::step()` with the option `direction = 'both'` works by comparing the AIC improvements from 
dropping each candidate variable, and adding each candidate variable between the upper and lower bound regressor sets supplied,
from the current model, and by dropping or adding the one variable that leads to the best AIC improvement (smallest AIC).

For example, assume that you are fitting a linear regression model with the upper set of variables $\mathcal{U} = \{X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5, X_6, X_7\}$, and lower set $\mathcal{L} = \{X_1\}$, and the starting object $\mathcal{S}_0 = \{X_1, X_3\}$, then the potential sets of retained regressors might be something like
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}_1 &= \{X_1, X_3, X_6\} &\text{  (add $X_6$)  }\\
\mathcal{S}_2 &= \{X_1, X_3, X_6, X_4\} &\text{  (add $X_4$)  }\\
\mathcal{S}_3 &= \{X_3, X_6, X_4\} &\text{  (drop $X_1$)  }\\
\mathcal{S}_4 &= \{X_3, X_6, X_4, X_7\} &\text{  (add $X_7$)  }\\
\mathcal{S}_5 &= \{X_3, X_4, X_7\} &\text{  (drop $X_6$)  }
\end{align}
$$
and so on, till no AIC improvements can be made.